# The input for my program gets printed out without first charater

Tags: c++

```cpp
char* val = new char[20];
std::cout << " enter item number : ";
std::cin.ignore();
std::cin.getline(val, 20);
val[strlen(val)] = '\0';
std::cout << val;
```

For example for input `123` the output is `23`

Comment: By removing `cin.ignore();`

Comment: Unrelated but... what is `val[strlen(val)] = '\0';` supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, when you call cin.ignore() to ignore the amount of characters you specify when you call it, up to the char you specify as a breakpoint.

```
char* val = new char[20];
std::cout << " enter item number : ";

std::cin.getline(val, 20);


// val[strlen(val)-1] = '\0'; can't understand what this is doing here
std::cout << val;
```

Comment: Thanks brother. My question was answered